# Backslash confusion using bash/sed to replace variable user name with variable name?

Tags: bash, sed

Using Bash, the following `sed` substitution replaces the user name in the input string with `%USERNAME` (which is a DOS variable):

```
echo "c:\\cygwin64\\home\\$USERNAME\SomeFolder" \
   | sed -e "s=\\$USERNAME\>=\\%USERNAME%="
```

The following fails to do the same:

```
echo "c:\\cygwin64\\home\\$USERNAME\SomeFolder" \
   | sed -e "s=home\\$USERNAME\>=home\\%USERNAME%="
```

**Context**

This is going into a bash function

```
cpawusr () { cygpath -aw "$@" | sed -e "s=\\home\\$USERNAME\>=\\home\\%USERNAME%=g" ; }
```

The function will be used by different users, and I want $USERNAME
to expand out when the function is called, hence the double quotes.

Comment: The second uses double quotes around the `sed` command, so the `$USERNAME` gets expanded before being passed to `sed`.  Usually, you should use single quotes around `sed` expressions.  In context, I suspect you simply don't want the `$` before `$USERNAME`.

Comment: I should clarify — the problematic `$USERNAME` is the second one (in the second command); you should have just `%USERNAME%` and not `%$USERNAME%` in the replacement material.

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan. I added some context to explain the double quotes.  I also removed the problematic `$`, but it still doesn't match.

Comment: If you want to change a word using sed, you can do it like this, too:
 `echo "Bye World" | sed "s/Bye/Hello/g"`

Comment: @FarbodAhmadian: the OP demonstrates that you can use characters other than a slash to mark the limits of each component of a `s///` command.  In context, `s=Bye=Hello=` is equivalent to `s/Bye/Hello/`.  I think your comment isn't helpful, for all it is trying to be helpful.

Comment: I don't think this question needs to be closed.  It has a simple reproduction in the question — and it does reproduce.  It is a subtle problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how many programs are interpreting backslashes.  One solution is to replace some of the double backslashes with *quadruple* backslashes:

```
echo "c:\\cygwin64\\home\\$USERNAME\SomeFolder" |
    sed -e "s=home\\\\$USERNAME\>=home\\\\%USERNAME%="
```

Another solution is to use single quotes where possible:

```
echo "c:\\cygwin64\\home\\$USERNAME\SomeFolder" |
    sed -e 's=home\\'"$USERNAME"'\>=home\\%USERNAME%='
```

In the original code with the double quotes, the shell parses the string, and replaces each `\\` pair by a single `\`.  Then `sed` sees a single backslash and uses that to escape the next character.  When you use quadruple backslashes, then `sed` sees `\\` and treats that as `\`, as intended.

In the single-quoted script, the shell doesn't interpret the data in single quotes, but it does expand `$USERNAME` in the double quotes.

I note that the `\>` notation requires GNU `sed`; BSD (macOS) `sed` does not recognize it, even with `-E` for extended regular expressions.

Comment: Seeing quadruple backslashes takes me back to `troff` macros.  Some of those used 8 or even 16 consecutive backslashes.  The mind boggles, but it worked and was necessary.

Comment: Thanks!  For some reason, I got into thinking that backslashes in quoted strings were protected, but simple testing proves me wrong.  I like your second example.  Less mental gymnastics to see what's going on.  I will try to reword the question's title to better reflect the nature of the problem.